# Dealing with the issue of embedded tomcat's port numbers when scaling the web container in a Heroku-like cloud

Tags: heroku, docker, embedded-tomcat-8, docker-compose

Say I have two web containers scaled as follows:

```
docker-compose scale web=2
```

The web container is executed as follows (from Dockerfile):

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/app/my-jar-server-1.0.jar" ]
```

What is the best strategy to ensure that the two different embedded tomcats listen to different ports (for instance if I want to build a Heroku-like infrastructure: [see foreman](http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/))?

In other words both containers are going to listen to the same port thereby causing a conflict.

Ideally I would need to round-robin requests to the two tomcat instances. I am looking for tools and ideas...

**edit 1**:

Here is what I've tried:

From docker-compose.yml:

```
loadbalancer:
  image: haproxy
  links:
      - web
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
web:
  build: ./web
```

From ./web/Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8
ADD ./bignibou-server-1.0.jar /app/bignibou-server-1.0.jar
ADD ./spring-cloud.properties /app/spring-cloud.properties
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_PROPERTIESFILE=/app/spring-cloud.properties
ENV SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=cloud
ENV SPRING_CLOUD_APP_NAME=bignibou
ENV CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/bignibou_dev
ENV REDISCLOUD_URL=redis://dummy:dummy@localhost:6379
ENV DYNO=dummy
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "java", "-jar", "/app/bignibou-server-1.0.jar" ]
```

Here is what I get:

```
loadbalancer_1 | [ALERT] 091/105717 (1) : Could not open configuration file /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg : No such file or directory
dockertests_loadbalancer_1 exited with code 1
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping dockertests_web_1...
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/threading", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/threading", line 505, in run
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.multiplexer", line 41, in _enqueue_output
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.log_printer", line 62, in _make_log_generator
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.container", line 139, in wait
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.client", line 999, in wait
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.client", line 78, in _post
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.sessions", line 425, in post
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.sessions", line 383, in request
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.sessions", line 486, in send
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/requests.adapters", line 374, in send
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'
```

**edit 2**: Ignore my edit 1, I was not able to reproduce the issue.

However, I was able to successfully start two instances on tomcat but I tried to access them through a browser:

```
http://172.17.42.1:8080/
```

to no avail. Can someone please help?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. One possible solution is Consul discovery at startup.

Comment: @Damo: thanks for your comment. Can you or someone else please elaborate on the suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach (without going down the Consul route) is to setup your "loadbalancer" container to be aware of your "web" containers eg:

```
web:
  image: tomcat

loadbalancer:
  image: haproxy
  links:
      - web
  ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Try the docker-compose documentation and specifically the section on "links": https://docs.docker.com/compose/yml/#links

Comment: Can you please bring some precision about how to set up tomcat and some pointers to reference documentation?